# Oracle SQL: Is it possible to create a table based on a selection and order by a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, datatable, datatables

I want to create a table by selecting some data from an other table and at the same time order them based on one (or more) of the columns. I provide the following example knowing that it is wrong. Is it generally possible to achieve such a table formation and if yes, is there any similar SQL statement that can achieve that?

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS (
SELECT
*
FROM A_RANDOM_TABLE
)
ORDER BY COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2;
```

Comment: Tables represent *unordered* sets, so "order by a column" doesn't make sense.

Comment: What do you want to achieve using `order by` in `CTAS`? even your code is wrong. it should be `CREATE **TABLE** NEW_TABLE_NAME AS`

Comment: @Tejash Just a new created table with data ordered by a specific column. Nothing more. Please note, I am new in SQL.

Comment: Ok, Not an issue. Gordon correctly stated that there is no such ordering in the table. table is unordered set.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your answer. Then, I presume that this is something not possible.

Comment: Read the 'CTAS using INDEX Hint' section of this, and the section after.  I'm not familiar enough to answer but perhaps this would work. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_create_table_select_ctas.htm

Comment: @GordonLinoff whilst it's true that heap tables are by definition unordered, if you create a new table with an ordered set, the rows will, in general, be inserted in the specified order (this relates to clustering factor; the more rows belonging to a single index entry that are in a block, the faster it is for Oracle to retrieve rows for a specified value). However, new rows inserted afterwards won't be inserted in the "right" order; they'll be slotted in wherever there is room (e.g. overwriting the spaced used by previously deleted rows, or at the end of the table).

Comment: ... following on from my previous comment: there are, however, Index Organized Tables (IOTs) which use an index to store the entire table, which may or may not suit the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 It's not so much that it isn't possible, but rather you are thinking of this wrong (I assume). If you what you are wanting is that whenever you select from this new table that the result set returned will be ordered, then you MUST specify that in your `SELECT` statement using the `ORDER BY` clause. Relying on the ordering of records in a table just isn't something that happens in SQL. Ordering is only done on data retrieval in your SELECT statement. There are some exceptions here, but they are very specialized usecases like IOTs mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @Boneist . . . The only plausible reason I can think of for wanting an "ordered table" is to remove the "order by" in a `select`.  Perhaps there are other reasons -- the OP doesn't provide any reason at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the question **is* quite ambiguous, you’re not wrong! However as I mentioned earlier, one reason for storing ordered results is to improve the clustering factor ( and therefore performance), but that only works if you’re querying the data in ways that take advantage of the low CF. And you add data to the table rarely.

Answer (score 3):

You should always sort your data at query time. There is **no** guarantee that Oracle would actually store the data in the order you insert the data. Even if you would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS
  SELECT *
    FROM A_RANDOM_TABLE
   ORDER BY COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2
;
```

In an ASSM Tablespace (and without "append"), Oracle will look for a free slot anywhere in the table.

Comment: . . Is this going to guarantee that `select * from new_table_name` retrieves the rows in order?

Comment: @ora-600 That's a good answer. So far I was doing a mistake. When I was creating such a kind of SQL statement I was using parenthesis after the `AS` and before the `;` i.e. `CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS (
SELECT
*
FROM A_RANDOM_TABLE
ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2
);` 
This was always giving me an error and thought that it is not possible to create and order at the same time. Using this in a simplified query, works! Nevertheless, in my particular situation (I didn't provide all the details in my main question as I wanted to make it short) it doesn't work so far (see next comment).

Comment: @ora-600 More specifically, my code creates a table by uniting several selections. For example:
`CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME AS
SELECT * FROM  A_RANDOM_TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A_RANDOM_TABLE_2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A_RANDOM_TABLE_3
ORDER BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2
`
This gives me the error "ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qkeAddDependentExpr1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []". Please note that the column names from each table are the same and of the same data type.

Comment: @Whitebeard13 you can also order by column position; you could try `order by 1, 2`, which would order by the first, then second columns in the selected column list. (If you want the 2nd and 4th columns to use in the order, it would be `order by 2, 4`, etc.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: in most cases this will return the data in the correct order but it's no guarantee. But the correct solution is to `ORDER BY` during read not write.

Comment: @Whitebeard13: Your ora-600 sounds like Bug 6530145 (UNION ALL + ORDER BY). A `UNION` removes duplicate records which results in an ordered output of the data. If you do not have to remove duplicate records, use `UNION ALL` this is much faster. Anyway... do the `order by` when selecting from the new table -- not while writing to the table. This is how databases work.

Answer (score 0):

Physical table order can be created and maintained with [Attribute Clustering](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/attcluster.htm).

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE_NAME
CLUSTERING BY LINEAR ORDER(COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2) AS
SELECT *
FROM A_RANDOM_TABLE
ORDER BY COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2;
```

While this literally answers your question it probably isn't the answer you're looking for.  Attribute clustering is *not* about providing a logical ordering.  As others have pointed out, the only way to guarantee sorting is to use the `ORDER BY` clause in your queries.  We do not want our tables strongly tied to the physical format of data - that caused problems that were literally the motivation for creating the relational model in the first place.

Attribute clustering helps provide a physical ordering to improve performance in several cases - index clustering factor, materialized zone maps in Exadata, etc.  Attribute clustering helps maintain the order during a `MOVE` or direct-path `INSERT`.  But it doesn't maintain the order for all DML statements, and it certainly does not guarantee the order of results when reading from the table.

Comment: Is this going to guarantee that select * from new_table_name retrieves the rows in order?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, it does not guarantee the order.